# How to use .htaccess with sub directories of directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ controller.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I go to a folder such as folder/subfolder/, it gives me a 404 error, although the folder exists.

How can I make this work with subdirectories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the pattern in your rule from `^([^/\.]+)/?$` to `^([^\.]+)/?$` so that it matches against slashes.

Comment: @ConnorrAndrewGurney'xo you should click on the green checkmark when your question gets answered so that your question is marked as resolved.